# Not able to deploy a war maven project with Jboss 7.0.2

Tags: maven-3, jboss7.x

I m trying to deploy a WAR maven project which contains a simple managed Bean and a xhtml page.
Earlier i create an EJB maven project which contains the entities and the session Bean..after deploying the rjb project i get an JAR executable file which i added it like a dependency to the WEB project..
but a problem while deploying the WAR of my web project
ive searched all day about a solution..with an intense headacke ,i soon going to give up..
this is the error:

```
17:48:07,781 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_38]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/GestionReclamation/services/EmployeBean : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_38]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_38]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:397) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:590) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:183) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103) [jboss-modules.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:201)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    ... 5 more

17:48:07,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Deployment of "GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\""}}
17:48:07,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopped deployment GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war in 41ms
17:48:07,825 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"GestionReclamationWEB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\""}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is compiled with JDK7 and JBoss runs with JDK6. This won't work, because JDK6 cannot execute class files compiled with JDK7.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) may help to understand the problem.